# Asymptotic upper bounds for some convolution sums

Tags: nt.number-theory

Roman Holowinsky proved (see arXiv:0809.1640v3, Theorem 2, page 3) some nice asymptotic upper bounds
for  sums

$$
S(d,x) = \sum_{1 \leq n \leq x} \vert f(n)g(n+d) \vert
$$

for given multiplicative functions $f,g$ and given fixed integer $d$ with $0 < \vert d \vert \leq x.$

Question:  What is known about the analogue convolution sums 
(that, however, do not seems to be a generalization of the above sums)

$$
S(a,b,h,x) = \sum_{1 \leq n,m \leq x,\; an + bm=h} \vert f(n)g(m) \vert
$$

for given multiplicative functions $f,g$ and
for fixed positive integers 
$$
a >0,\;b >0,
$$
real $x$,  and fixed appropriate integer $h.$

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of work on such problems.  One significant paper is 
Peter Shiu's A Brun Titchmarsh theorem for multiplicative functions in 
Crelle (1980).  See also Mohan Nair's paper in Acta Arithmetica 1992 which is
available at

http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa62/aa6234.pdf